# How to define avro schema to get xml attribute with ConvertRecord on Nifi?

Tags: xml, attributes, apache-nifi, avro

I have a question regarding avro schema for XMLReader on Nifi.

When using ConvertRecord with XMLReader, I defined avro schema to represent structure of xml so that conversion works as expected.

This works xml which does not have any attributes inside itself, but does not work for the one with attributes.

How can I define avro schema to get attribute values of xml (="abc") in the following example?

```
<root>
<tag1 attribute1="abc">
<tag1/>
</root>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a limitation of converting between XML and other formats. Avro schemas don't have a way to represent attributes on fields. Also, the specifics of what to do with the attribute would be very dependent on the destination format. For example, where should the attribute value end up in JSON, CSV, etc, when those formats don't have field attributes.